# ConfigParser using SFINAE to implement get_as<type>()

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, sfinae

So in order to get more into metaprogramming I tried to write a config file parser that can return the parsed values as a specific type using a

```
template<typename T> T get_as(std::string key)
```

like interface. Since I'm storing the parsed config file internally as a string-string map, I still need to transform most of the data before I can return it. So I used the type_traits header to transform the data depending on the requested type. I made the following assumptions:

- All non trivial types must supply a constructor that takes a std::string to construct themself.
- Strings are true iff they spell true (impartial to lower/upper/mixedcase), and false iff they spell false, else we raise an exception

The implementation is header only and can be found on my [github page](https://github.com/datosh/ConfigReader/blob/master/ConfigReader/ConfigReader.h).

```
/// INTEGRAL TYPES
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value && !std::is_same<bool, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
T get_as(std::string key)
{
    // Implementation
}

/// FLOATING TYPES
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_floating_point<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
T get_as(std::string key)
{
    // Implementation
}

/// BOOL
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<bool, T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
T get_as(std::string key)
{
    // Implementation
}

/// COMPLEX TYPE
template<class T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_class<T>::value>::type* = nullptr>
T get_as(std::string key)
{
    // Implementation
}
```

The questions I have is whether this is an okay design to split my executing like this depending on the requested type. Or is there a better way to implement a type dependent get_as interface?

Comment: Subsitution Failure Is Not Errr... Atomic?

Comment: This might be more appropriate on the [Code-Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com) Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @TobySpeight thanks - I did not know there was such a thing. Thats why I tried to tag it accordingly. Will use the other site next time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exceptions should be exceptional.

You should audit the config file and ensure no exceptions can occur: both when saving, and possibly version it so you can detect an older version.  Then a failure where the config file is not valid is now exceptional.

It is also probable that instead of loading a string-string map, you should load the config data with validation at the point of loading, instead of at the point of use.

Have the layout of the config data, and the serialization, be linked.  An archive system like:

```
struct config {
  int x;
  std::string bar;
  bool b;

  template<class A, class Config,
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<std::decay_t<Config>, config>>::value, int>* =nullptr
  >
  friend void Archive( A& a, std::string name, Config& config ) {
    auto tag = Archive(a, name, ArchiveTag);
    Archive(a, "x", config.x);
    Archive(a, "bar", config.bar);
    Archive(a, "b", config.b); // etc
  }
};
```

now we have an archive system that saves and loads in a type-safe manner.  Type errors are caught early.  Errors can be exceptions, or rather stored in the `Archive` type and possible handled en-mass.

Maybe a default archive exists which is read from if the file you are reading is missing a field.

Comment: That seems like a good way to avoid the on request casting/transforming of data, but I would no longer be able to request the value in a different type, wouldn't I? And I have to add two lines in the Implementation (storage space in config and another Archive line) for each line of config file. How would this implementation scale for a config file with hundreds of lines?

Comment: @dat Requesting something as the wrong type is a type error, no?  There are very few valid reasons for a fixed field to be either a boolean or an integer.  Basically I moved the required type knowledge in the code from *every point of use, where a mistake causes an exception in whatever code wanted config data*, to *one spot, where an error handling can be centralized*.  Exceptions where-ever you read config data means either an unstable/unpredictable program, or a metric tonne of exception handling and unit tests around every config access!

Comment: Yeah I do get that point. My thought was that I could use this for complex types, swap the type T from class Foo to class Bar, and the constructor handles the rest. But what about my other question? Your approach doesn't seem to scale very well, does it?